# How to get result from query with multiple classes in simple java without using hql,jpql query

Tags: java

When we crate jpql query in java like as below 
Select a.*,b.* c.* from a,b,c where a.id=b.id and b.id=c.id

the result is List of object array,so first array is value of a table ,second is value of b table  likewise

My question is when we write same query in sql then what is the result .and how get value of each table .

Answer (score 0):

What you usually do is running different queries for different data.

Information coming from the database have a form of a [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). A ResultSet has different fields.

Example:

```
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
            PersistenceProvider.getInstance().prepareStatement("select a.*, c.* from actor a left join city c on ...");

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (resultSet.next()){
        ActorBean actorBean = new ActorBean();
        actorBean.setActorId(resultSet.getInt("actor_id"));
        actorBean.setFirstName(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
        actorBean.setLastName(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
        actorBean.setLastUpdate(resultSet.getTimestamp("last_update"));

        actorBeanList.add(actorBean);

        CityBean cityBean = new CityBean();
        cityBean.setCityId(resultSet.getInt("city_id"));
        cityBeanList.add(cityBean);
    }
```

You can create instances of different classes and put values taken from the ResultSet in those istances.

In the example above, you don't have to create always instances of ActorBean, you can also create instances of other classes.

Comment: My query  have left outer join with four table ,and i want value of four table

Comment: In jpql i know how to get value in list of object array ,but in simple jave i dont understand how to get value of each table field.when i creating quert and adding a.class that time i get all value of table a .("select a.* from a",a.class)

Comment: your answer is right but ,my database table don't have any relation (mapping ex- one to many ,many to one,many to many ) ,in that case is it possible to add multiple outer join and create query in jpql ?